# How to use navigationDestination when each new view also requires the selected state?

Tags: swift, swiftui

For example, we can see Apple's approach in the food truck sample code

They have

```
ParentGrid
.navigationDestination(for: Donut.ID.self) { donutID in
            DonutEditor(donut: model.donutBinding(id: donutID))
}
```

and then in each cell simply

```
GridCell {
 NavigationLink(value: donut.id) {
   DonutCellToBeSelected...
 }
}
```

That works but let's say I have another view that I need to pop on the stack INSIDE the DonutEditor.

In that case, I can't just do NavigationLink(value: donut.id) again. How can I allow DonutEditor -> DetailViewPage2 but also receiving a donutBinding?

```
DonutEditor{
   NavigationLink(value: ???) {
      DetailViewPage2...
   }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do `NavigationLink(value:)` inside of your `DonutEditor` view? The `DonutEditor` view gets the binding which you can pass on to `DetailViewPage2`, no?

Comment: @HarshadKale how will navigationDestination which view to push to? It's based on the value, if it's the same value for both views. It wont know

Comment: I can't exactly tell what you are trying to achieve here but from what I can gather, you have a grid of items to which you are attaching `navigationDestination(for:)` modifier to land on say `DonutEditor` view. From the `DonutEditor` View, you have one more level of navigation to `DetailViewPage2`. Is that correct? What is the trigger inside `DonutEditor` view that will be responsible for launching the `DetailViewPage2`?

Comment: @HarshadKale correct, its the same. A NavigationLink around a certain view. Post some code example and you will realize that it won't work because you are passing the same donut.id value.

Comment: Cannot post code blocks in comments here, so posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by another forum. The proper solution.

```
enum DonutRoute: Hashable {
    case edit(Donut.ID)
    case detail(Donut.ID)
}

ParentGrid.navigationDestination(for: DonutRoute.self) { route in
    switch route {
        case let .edit(id):
            DonutEditor(donut: model.donutBinding(id: id))
        case let .detail(id):
            DetailViewPage2(…)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion in comments above, I think this might work for you.

```
ParentGrid
  .navigationDestination(for: Donut.ID.self) { donutID in
    DonutEditor(donut: model.donutBinding(id: donutID))
  }
```

In `DonutEditor.swift`

```
struct DonutEditor: View {
  @Binding var donut: Donut

  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailViewPage2(id: donut.id)) {
      Text(verbatim: "Show Details") // Tapping this will launch DetailViewPage2
    }
  }
}
```

In `DetailViewPage2.swift`

```
struct DetailViewPage2: View {
    var id: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text(verbatim: String(id)) // whatever details you want to show
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I’ve updated the question to better illustrate the problem. Can you update your answer

Comment: I think my answer would still apply as is. Your entire navigation path is like this == `DonutGridView` -> `DonutEditor` -> `DetailViewPage2` correct? Which means `DetailViewPage2` is launched from `DonutEditor` view and `DonutGridView` doesn't need to know about it.